# how to deploy a smart contract in ethereum using web3j

Tags: go-ethereum, web3j, java

i am following this tutorial [tutorial](https://docs.web3j.io/getting_started.html#transactions)

under the section **Working with smart contracts with Java smart contract wrappers** i followed the same steps but i am getting `RunTimeException` here is the full stack trace

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: smartcontract.Counter1.<init>(java.lang.String, org.web3j.protocol.Web3j, org.web3j.crypto.Credentials, org.web3j.tx.gas.ContractGasProvider)
    at org.web3j.tx.Contract.deploy(Contract.java:366)
    at org.web3j.tx.Contract.deploy(Contract.java:403)
    at org.web3j.tx.Contract.lambda$deployRemoteCall$5(Contract.java:426)
    at org.web3j.protocol.core.RemoteCall.send(RemoteCall.java:30)
    at smartcontract.CounterDemo.deployContract(CounterDemo.java:37)
    at controllers.SmartContractController$$anonfun$counterContractDemo$1.apply(SmartContractController.scala:64)
    at controllers.SmartContractController$$anonfun$counterContractDemo$1.apply(SmartContractController.scala:58)
```

and here is my code 
a code snippet of Counter1.java

```
public static RemoteCall<Counter1> deploy(Web3j web3j, Credentials credentials, BigInteger gasPrice, BigInteger gasLimit) {
        return deployRemoteCall(Counter1.class, web3j, credentials, gasPrice, gasLimit, BINARY, "");
    }

    public static RemoteCall<Counter1> deploy(Web3j web3j, TransactionManager transactionManager, BigInteger gasPrice, BigInteger gasLimit) {
        return deployRemoteCall(Counter1.class, web3j, transactionManager, gasPrice, gasLimit, BINARY, "");
    }

    public static Counter1 load(String contractAddress, Web3j web3j, Credentials credentials, BigInteger gasPrice, BigInteger gasLimit) {
        return new Counter1(contractAddress, web3j, credentials, gasPrice, gasLimit);
    }

    public static Counter1 load(String contractAddress, Web3j web3j, TransactionManager transactionManager, BigInteger gasPrice, BigInteger gasLimit) {
        return new Counter1(contractAddress, web3j, transactionManager, gasPrice, gasLimit);
    }
```

CounterDemo.java

```
public class CounterDemo {

    public String deployContract() {
        String deploy = "";
        BigInteger GAS_LIMIT = BigInteger.valueOf(6721975L);
        BigInteger GAS_PRICE = BigInteger.valueOf(20000000000L);
        try {

            Web3j web3j = Web3j.build(new org.web3j.protocol.http.HttpService("http://localhost:8080"));
            Credentials credentials = WalletUtils.loadCredentials("pswd",
                    "path to privatekey/UTC--2018-12-15T12-06-10.************************************1");
            System.out.println("credentails address " + credentials.getAddress());
            Counter1 counter = Counter1.deploy(web3j, credentials, GAS_PRICE,
                    GAS_LIMIT ).send();

            //Counter.deploy(web3j, credentials, GAS_PRICE,GAS_LIMIT);
            deploy = counter.getContractAddress();
            System.out.println("address is {}" + deploy);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } // defaults to http://localhost:8545/
        catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return deploy;
    }

}
```

and here is the play controller action on which i am getting a contract deployed address

```
def counterContractDemo() = Action {
    val web3j = Web3j.build(new HttpService("http://localhost:8080/"))
    val CounterDemo = new CounterDemo();

    Ok(CounterDemo.deployContract())
  }
```

i am using playframework 2.3.4  and passing the right amount of parameters for Counter1's deplo method still the exception shows NoSuchMethodException how is this happening is there anything missing ?which is causing the issue any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

```
protected Counter1(String contractAddress, Web3j web3j, TransactionManager transactionManager, ContractGasProvider gasProvider) {
    super(BINARY, contractAddress, web3j, transactionManager, gasProvider);
}
```

If i remember good, I had this problem and solved it by adding this to the generated java class.